# gRPC error returns with unexpected details field

Tags: c++, node.js, error-handling, grpc

I'm implementing gRPC error handling in my C++ server, which has routes called by another, nodejs-based, server (which is actually the client in this case).

My problem is that the `error_details` param passed to the `grpc::Status` constructor on the C++ side is not the same as the `error_details` the client receives.

C++ server:

```
return grpc::Status(
    isError ? grpc::StatusCode::UNKNOWN : grpc::StatusCode::OK,
    "application-specific error code", // the error_message param
    "Extended error details"           // the error_details param
);
```

NodeJS client:

```
try {
  await grpc.makeCall({params: 12345})
} catch(err) {
  const { details, message } = err
  console.log({ details, message }); 
  // -> { details: "application-specific error code", message: "2 UNKNOWN application-specific error code" }
  // Expected message:
  // -> { details: "Extended error", message: "application-specific error code" }
}
```

to clarify, the details field in the client contains the message field from the server, while the message field in the client contains the message field from the server plus a gRPC status code as a prefix.

I did note, however, that the details field I'm after, is available under this (incredibly straightforward) prop:

```
err.metadata._internal_repr['grpc-status-details-bin'][0].toString() // Originally a buffer
```

---

So my question is:
What the heck? am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different APIs here have different representations of the same underlying protocol information, and they happen to use names that collide. For reference, see the [protocol specification](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md). In that C++ API, the `error_message` parameter corresponds to the "Status-Message" part of the response, and the `error_details` parameter corresponds to the `grpc-status-details-bin` custom metadata item. As stated in [this comment](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/status.h#L114) the intention is that the `error_details` parameter will contain a serialized `google.rpc.Status` proto message.

In the Node API, the `details` value corresponds to the "Status-Message" part of the response (which, again, was the `error_message` parameter in C++). The `message` value is just an aggregate user-readable string that combines the status code, the human-readable name of the status code, and the details string. As mentioned in the question, the `grpc-status-details-bin` metadata item does not have a special accessor, it's just in the metadata value.